# Bootstrap grid issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So i've been trying to figure out how to make spaces in between each columns of col-sm-4 and couldn't really find a way how to make the spacing. As you can see I there is no spacing in between the columns.

[image]

Need something like this:
[image]

```
            <div class="inner_img">
              <img src="img/tablets/phoca_thumb_m_1.png" class="center-block">
            </div>

            <h5>Memorial Code: ...</h5>

            <p>.</p>

          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 phocagallery-box-file">
            <img src="img/tablets/phoca_thumb_m_2.png" class="center-block">
            <h5>Memorial Code: ...</h5>

            <p>.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 phocagallery-box-file">
            <img src="img/tablets/phoca_thumb_m_3.png" class="center-block">
            <h5>Memorial Code: ...</h5>

            <p>.</p>
          </div>
```

CSS:

```
.phocagallery-box-file {
  background: #525900;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding `padding` to the box holding the `col-md-4` will overwrite Bootstraps' default gutter padding and hence removing the spacing between columns.

The two options are to add `padding` to an inner element, than where the `col-md-4`s are placed.

Example:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 phocagallery-box-file">
    <div class="innner-box">
        <img class="center-block" src="img/tablets/phoca_thumb_m_2.png">

        <h5>Memorial Code: ...</h5>

        <p>.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.phocagallery-box-file {
  background: #525900;
  display: block;
}

.inner-box {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

and / or

Play around with `border`s and adjusting their thickness.

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xareyo/p8o26ecc/)

Comment: So I should use border instead? margin isn't cutting it as it moves the last box to the bottom.

Comment: that inner-box, didn't fix the spacing though.